# Android: Google Filament GLTF/GLB model not displayed

Tags: android, 3d, gltf

My issue is that I'm trying to make a `SurfaceView` display a 3D model that's just a small part of the whole application layout. The layout includes multiple views for displaying other data; however, as soon as I create the `ModelViewer` the `SurfaceView` vanishes. When I use version `1.9.9` of Filament the layout is displayed, but heavily pixelated and seems to make other layout elements disappear. With `v1.7.0` the other elements don't dissapear, but nothing is displayed.

I'm using the following version in Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-android:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:gltfio-android:1.7.0'
```

I have a model copying to the assets folder as I've seen in their Kotlin example:
https://github.com/google/filament/tree/main/android/samples/sample-gltf-viewer

This is my Java attempt at loading a custom GLTF 2.0 model exported from Blender:

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.view.Choreographer;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import com.google.android.filament.Engine;
import com.google.android.filament.utils.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Model implements Choreographer.FrameCallback {

    static {
        Utils.INSTANCE.init();
    }

    private final String TAG = Model.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private ModelViewer modelViewer;
    private Engine engine;
    private Choreographer choreographer;
    private final String modelFilename = "models/modelTest.glb";

    @Override
    public void doFrame(long currentTime) {
        choreographer.postFrameCallback(this);
        modelViewer.render(currentTime);
    }

    public Model(Context context, ConstraintLayout layout) {

        this.context = context;
        choreographer = Choreographer.getInstance();

        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        layout.addView(surfaceView);
        engine = Engine.create();
        modelViewer = new ModelViewer(surfaceView, engine, null);
        loadModel(modelFilename);
        choreographer.postFrameCallback(this);
    }

    private void loadModel(String filepath) {
        try {
            InputStream buffer = context.getAssets().open(filepath);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.available()];
            buffer.read(bytes);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
            modelViewer.loadModelGlb(byteBuffer);
            modelViewer.transformToUnitCube(new Float3(0,0,0));
        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Edit 1:

This is what displays when using any version above 1.9.4. The choreographer loop makes the static portions look like static noise on a TV. The red parts appear to be a small portion of the model.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this a while back by making a copy of the `ModelViewer` class and making a custom `ModelViewer3D` class with a new constructor, which was a nice solution, because it gives you more control over the options than you would normally with the given `ModelViewer`.

The `uiHelper` `isOpaque` field needed to be set to false to fix the above issue, and for a transparent background of the surface view the renderer needed to reset the clear options (which I made a separate function for, shown below).

```
     constructor(surfaceView: SurfaceView, engine: Engine = Engine.create(), manipulator: Manipulator? = null, isOpaque: Boolean) : this(engine) {
        cameraManipulator = manipulator ?: Manipulator.Builder()
                .targetPosition(kDefaultObjectPosition.x, kDefaultObjectPosition.y, kDefaultObjectPosition.z)
                .viewport(surfaceView.width, surfaceView.height)
                .build(Manipulator.Mode.ORBIT)

        this.surfaceView = surfaceView
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(surfaceView, cameraManipulator)
        displayHelper = DisplayHelper(surfaceView.context)
        uiHelper.isOpaque = isOpaque
        uiHelper.renderCallback = SurfaceCallback()
        uiHelper.attachTo(surfaceView)
        addDetachListener(surfaceView)
    }

    fun makeBackgroundTransparent() {
        val options = renderer.clearOptions
        options.clear = true
        renderer.clearOptions = options
    }
```

I also ended up using this version of the library since it was the latest at the time:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-android:1.9.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.9.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:gltfio-android:1.9.9'
```